# Modifying visual states in blend?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, blend

I'm playing around with a 3rd party package for charting ([Modern UI Charts](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/)).  It looks great and seems to work for what I need.

But in the example code that comes with the package, all of the styles and templates are in a resource dictionary in `Generic.xaml`, as they are all custom (lookless) controls.

But I want to override a lot of what's in that `Generic.xaml` file, including some visual states.  Specifically, in the chart I want to use, it animates out and then in when any of the data changes.  I want to turn that off.

If I try to edit the templates or styles in blend, I see some of the code from the default xaml, but not the visual states.  Is there a way to modify those?

Or how can I completely override the `Generic.xaml` and replace it with my own?

Comment: are you inheriting the controls? or just want to redefine the styles and templates?

Comment: Just want to redefine the styles and templates- in particular turn off that visual state if I can...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is easy to override when you are inheriting the control and creating your own by `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata`

I am not sure about your implementation. typically if you create a style for the concerned type it overrides the existing unless you use `BasedOn` Attribute.

example

```
<Style TargetType="local:PieChart" BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseChartStyle}">
    <Setter Property="ChartAreaStyle" Value="{StaticResource PieChartChartAreaStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="PlotterAreaStyle" Value="{StaticResource PieChartPlotterAreaStyle}" />
</Style>
```

if you redfine above as

```
<Style TargetType="local:PieChart" >
    ... your style
</Style>
```

it will override the existing style

or you can choose to override specific property by deriving from existing style for the element by `BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:PieChart}}"`

```
<Style TargetType="local:PieChart" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type local:PieChart}}">
    <Setter Property="ChartAreaStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyChartAreaStyle}" />
</Style>
```

In similar way you can override `Template` property of your desired element with your own version.